# Setting the value of a int on button click

Tags: android, eclipse, onclick, integer

How do I set the value of a int when clicking a button?

I tried this:

```
    final int a1_val = 0;

    a1_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {a1_val= a1_val+1;;};});
```

But it is saying that : The final local variable a1_val, cannot be assigned since it is defined in an enclosing type.

Comment: AS simple as this: `a1_val = 1;` and remove `final` from the declaration.

Comment: if I do this it says that: cannot refer to a non-variable a1_val inside an inner class defined in a different method

Comment: I think you should read some tutorial about **variables scope**. It will help you a lot.

Comment: @eeschimosu declare your `a1_val` as a class variable. Just that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make 2 changes. Move a1_val's declaration out of the method it's in and near the top of your enclosing class (outside of any method). Then, remove the final keyword from a1_val's declaration.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that the problem was the declaration of integers inside of the method!

Answer (score 0):

```
final int a1_val = 0; //here you have declarated thar a1_v1 is final = constant
```

if you want change the value of `a1_v1` :remove `final`

```
  int a1_val = 0; //delete final
  a1_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    a1_val= a1_val+1;
    };
   });
```

Comment: if I do this it says that: cannot refer to a non-variable a1_val inside an inner class defined in a different method